# Should i pass an object or a Func/Action to a method in C#

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

There are any differences between passing a simple plain object, or a lambda function that return the same object and which option to chose in terms of performance/readibility?

Given an example class, i don't understand in which scenarios should i chose to make a method require a Func/Action paramether instead of just the object that it returns, when most of the times just a simple inline lambda function will be used.

```cs
public static class TestClass
{
    public static void someOperation<T>(Func<T> test) where T : notnull
    {
        var x = test.Invoke();
        
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
    }
    public static void someOperation<T>(T test) where T : notnull
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
    }
    public static void someOperationOnString(Func<string> test)
    {
        string x = test.Invoke();

        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
    public static void someOperationOnString(string test)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(test);
    }
}

TestClass.someOperation(() => "Hello, World!"); // Hello, World!
TestClass.someOperation("Hello, World!"); // Hello, World!
TestClass.someOperation(() => 1); // 1
TestClass.someOperation(() => new { test = "some test" }); // { test = some test }

TestClass.someOperationOnString(() => "my random string"); // my random string
TestClass.someOperationOnString("my random string"); // my random string
```

I know that the Func will be invoked after the method call, but basically in both case it will be invoked so there shouldn't be any differences in terms of performances.
I also noticed that many libraries/frameworks uses the Func option, but i don't understand the advantages and when to choose one or the other. (e.g. Asp.net Core)

Comment: the obligatory [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) link

Comment: Using `Func` as parameter is always performance penalty. It should be used only if you understand what do you expect from callback.

Comment: All these variations are doing different things so the answer to your question is "it depends", and makes this an opinion based question.

Comment: I think the example may be too simple, actually. A better example would be `void SomeMethod (string arg)` vs `void SomeMethod (Func<int,string> argFunc)` < where the callback actually gets parameterized by the caller. You cannot do that with a plain argument.

Comment: To show what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/56EPwc

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> There are any differences between passing a simple plain object, or a lambda function that return the same object

The main difference is that using a lambda is more abstract. You could generate the object on demand, thus avoiding potentially expensive initialization if the object will not in fact be needed. Or you could generate different objects each time it is called.

> which option to chose in terms of performance/readibility?

Use the simplest, least abstract, option that fulfills your requirements. You should in general try to avoid *unnecessary* abstraction to increase readability. The difficulty is to know what abstraction is, or will become, necessary.

> Given an example class, i don't understand in which scenarios should i chose to make a method require a Func/Action paramether instead of just the object that it returns, when most of the times just a simple inline lambda function will be used

In this particular example all alternatives does the exact same thing, so the simplest and best option in this particular case is to use a regular string:

```
public static void someOperationOnString(string test)
{
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
TestClass.someOperationOnString("my random string"); // my random string
```

Or, if you want to be able to print arbitrary types:

```
public static void someOperation<T>(T test) where T : notnull
{
    Console.WriteLine(test.ToString());
}
TestClass.someOperation(1);
```

Comment: @Fildor My guess is the DV is for answering an opinion-based question? Also, this doesn't strictly answer the question.

Comment: All of which is debatable if you ask me @DavidG. There might not be a hard rule when to use which, but where do we actually have that, really? Not that often. And given OP is Rep 1, answering "use the least complex that does the job" is a useful answer, after all. ( Assuming we agree on "when to use which" is what is asked )

Comment: @Fildor A useful answer, but I'd argue that's a good as a comment.